# Getting user id from Posts table

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-5.8

I have a route for destroying a Post, how can I make so that the one who can access the route is only the Post creator? For example, I have a Post with id number 3 and the user id is 5, so the only one who can delete number 3 is only user id 5. I've tried messing with middleware but not lucky enough to get it to work.

**CekStatus.php (Middleware)**

```php
class CekStatus
{
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        $userId = $request->id;
        $user = Post::where('id', $userId)->select('user_id')->pluck('user_id')->first();

        if ($user === Auth::id()) {
            return $next($request);
        }

        return redirect('/'); //redirect anyware.
    }
}
```

**Route**

```php
Route::get('/hapus/{id}','PostController@destroy')->middleware('cekstatus');
```

**Kernel.php**

```php
protected $middlewareGroups = [
    'web' => [
        \App\Http\Middleware\EncryptCookies::class,
        \Illuminate\Cookie\Middleware\AddQueuedCookiesToResponse::class,
        \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession::class,
        // \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\AuthenticateSession::class,
        \Illuminate\View\Middleware\ShareErrorsFromSession::class,
        \App\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken::class,
        \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\SubstituteBindings::class,
        'cekstatus' => \App\Http\Middleware\CekStatus::class,
    ],

    'api' => [
        'throttle:60,1',
        'bindings',
    ],
];
```

Output:

> ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS

Answer (score 1):

You should be using Policy here, the middleware is not used for authorization purposes. More on this in the docs [here](https://laravel.com/docs/master/authorization#writing-policies).

The docs use your example as well, instead of update you can create a delete function and then to use it in your controller you can add this:

```
if (auth()->user()->can('delete', $post)) {
    // delete it code here.
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but i still getting error 

"Call to a member function can() on null"

Comment: that means that you don't have an authenticated user logged in